# WIX automatically reset cookies on reload

Tags: cookies, wix, velo

Just noticed that the cookies set in my Wix website are automatically getting cleared on reloading the page. It was working fine recently. I haven't made any changes to the site after that. Does anyone know if it is due to any update in Wix?

Is there any option to remove `"cookie-consent-policy-client"` from wix `serviceTopology`